# set properties for ShimFileCreationInformation object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sharepoint, microsoft-fakes, sharepoint-clientobject

I am writing some unit test cases using fakes framework. I am using an object `ShimFileCreationInformation` from `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Fakes` namespace. Now, I pass this object to a function. Inside the function, I am trying to assign a value to the Url property.

```
fileCreationInformation.Url = value;
```

But even though the value is present, nothing gets assigned to Url properly and it remains null. Is there any workaround for this problem? To make things worse, there is not documentation available on `ShimFileCreationInformation` object.

**Code sample:**

```
ShimFileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new ShimFileCreationInformation();
SomeFunction(fileCreationInformation);
```

**SomeFunction :**

```
public void SomeFunction(FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation)
{
     fileCreationInformation.Url = value; // This statement had so effect on fileCreationInformation.Url
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code that duplicates the problem?

Comment: @paqogomez Updated with code.

Comment: Where does value come from? Have you ensured it is not null or empty? Also, I have not worked with this but do you need to call .Update() on the fileCreationInformation object?

Comment: @Aditi did you try the code I gave in the Answer below?

Answer (score 0):

`fileCreationInformation.Url = value;`

Setting the value directly as above will not work since you are setting the value of the Shim and not the actual object. You need to use `ShimFileCreationInformation.AllInstances.UrlGet` so thay whenever the Url Get is called it will return the value you specify.

Your code should look something like below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void derived_test()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        ShimFileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new ShimFileCreationInformation();

        ShimFileCreationInformation.AllInstances.UrlGet = (instance) => value;

        SomeFunction(fileCreationInformation);
    }
}

public void SomeFunction(FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation)
{
    var url = fileCreationInformation.Url; 

    // Check url variable above. It should be set to value

    fileCreationInformation.Url = value; // This statement will not work since you are trying to set the value of the Shim and you need to use `ShimFileCreationInformation.AllInstances.UrlGet` to set property value for Shims
}
```

Comment: But that requires changing the code of the method which is being tested.. so I can't do that...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test here?